# jquery cycle image loading problem

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-cycle

hi 
i have a slideshow i created with jquery and jquery cyle its working fine but when i cick on refresh page all images shows on the page for while and then hide and slideshow works fine how can i fix that is this a css problem ? or its normal

Comment: Next time, please add some punctuation, it's hard to follow what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use css to put

```
display:none
```

on any images you want.  Either use a css file or style="" in your HTML. The browser shouldn't display them then when the page loads.